# what does $a^* \cup b^*$ mean?

Tags: automata

I have to provide a DFA for the following language: $L=\{w|w$ is any string not in $a^* \cup b^*\}$

what does $a^* \cup b^*$ mean?

Comment: $a^{\ast}$ is the language of all strings that contain only $a$. Same for $b^{\ast}$. Union of them is the language of all strings that contain only $a$ or only $b$.

Comment: so it can be any string with a or b.

Comment: The language $L$ in your question is the language of strings that contain both $a$ and $b$. $ab\in L$, but $aaa\notin L$ and $b\notin L$.

Comment: a* can contain the empty character as well right?

Comment: I think that the problem is reduced to $L=\{w|w$ is any string not in $a^*$ or $b^*\}$

Comment: Indeed, any number of a's, including 0.

Comment: so $b\in L$ right?, but $ba \notin L$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52566/discussion-between-galc127-and-themathnoob).

Answer (score 1):

$\cup$ is the usual set union symbol. $a^*$ is the set $\{ \epsilon, a, aa, aaa, \dots\}$; $b^*$ likewise is $\{ \epsilon, b, bb, bbb, \dots\}$. The union is $\{ \epsilon, a, aa, aaa, \dots, b, bb, bbb, \dots\}$.